# Java IDE faster/lighter than Netbeans, for Windows

Tags: windows, netbeans

I am developing Java applications.

Is there one version fastest or lighter of Netbeans?

I'm using 7.3 version on Windows 7, but sometimes is hangs (halt), my version is consuming a lot of memory, I removed plugins or module, but is very slow still.

I'm thinking that Netbeans is very heavy...

Answer (score 2):

- Get the NetBeans that [matches your programming language](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)
- [How to improve Netbeans performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229763/395857)
- Nuke unnecessary plug-ins (as you did)
- Consider buying a SSD, more RAM (maybe it's swapping?), or switching to Sublime.

Comment: Ah, Sublime Text... It makes a lot of justice to its name: sleek, fast, extremely versatile. It does offer a bazillion options for language support, yet is lighter than any other IDE I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

• Better consider updating Netbeans to version 8.0 .This might cope with halting and other flaws.

• Disable the unnecessary plugins and modules.

[This version is much better than previou ones]